# Hive Alter External Table and Update Schema

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am looking for a command to add columns and update schema for my Hive External table backed by Avro schema.

Here is what I have tried so far.

I have a Hive External Table with Avro backed Schema created with this command -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `person_hourly`(
  'personid' string COMMENT '', 
  'name' string COMMENT '' 
  )
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  'partitiontime' string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://nameservice1/web/PersonData/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///schemas/PersonV1.avsc'
  )
```

I would like to add additional columns and update schema for this table.

`alter table person_hourly ADD COLUMNS (lastname string ) SET TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url' = 'hdfs:///schemas/PersonV2.avsc')`

But I cannot do this since I get an error 
`FAILED: ParseException line 1:64 missing EOF at 'SET' near ')'`

So I tried adding column separately, which worked, but I cannot update the schema 
`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. at least one column must be specified for the table`

Comment: Did you leave on `ADD COLUMNS` when you tried to do `SET`? If so, why?

Comment: I was trying to both add column and set properties, hence I had both in there.  I also tried just setting properties ( no ADD COLUMNS ) , but then ran into the last error I mentioned 
` atleast one column must be ... `

Comment: You shouldn't need columns. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTableProperties

Comment: This worked for me @cricket_007, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Data Definition Language (DDL) for `ALTER TABLE` can [be found here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTableProperties)

> ```
> ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES table_properties;
>  
> table_properties:
>   : (property_name = property_value, property_name = property_value, ... )
> ```

And your comment

> I tried adding column separately, which worked

I think that's what you should do. Add the column, then set the properties

Answer (score 0):

if you modify the schema in the hdfs, it will be detected by Hive. Hive read the schema on runtime, it doesn't save any schema information when you use avsc through avro.schema.url

Regards,
Hector

Comment: Yes.. I had to overwrite the existing schema file with a new one , essentially keeping the name constant and that worked.   My original question was about how to change the schema through Alter command, which is still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me..
You can change the schema definition in avsc file (with proper formatting)  then can use simply alter command with setting path of updated schema file.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES ("path of updated schema  avsc format file")
```